# Vertical and horizontal align in multicolumn and multirow

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I have big issues with alllign in multicolumn and multirow. In I need vertical allign in `multicolumn` with content 'a' and 'b'. Also I need horizontal and vertical allign in `multirow`. Is there way to do it? I will be grateful if someone help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}                 % customize page layout
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}                 % multirow for table (rowspan)

\geometry{paper=a4paper, landscape,hmargin=28.5mm,vmargin=20mm}

\setlength\parindent{0cm}   % no indent for whole document
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0cm}   % padding either side of each column (only horizontal)

% document start
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr#1-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}

  \begin{tabular}{
  | P{1.4cm}
  | M{1.4cm}
  | M{1.4cm}
  | P{7.6cm}
  | P{6.4cm}
  | P{1.2cm}
  | P{1.2cm}
  | P{1.2cm}
  | P{2.2cm}
  |
}

\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\rule[-0.8cm]{0cm}{1cm} a} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{b} \\

\hline
0 & 1 \par \footnotesize{(1)} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 &  \\\cline{1-8}

\rule[-0.8cm]{0cm}{1cm} & & &
\multirow{3}{7.6cm}{%
Question \hfill $\bigcirc$ \strut  Yes  $\bigcirc$ No \newline
Question \hfill $\bigcirc$ \strut  Yes  $\bigcirc$ No \newline
Question \hfill $\bigcirc$ \strut  Yes  $\bigcirc$ No \newline
Question \hfill $\bigcirc$ \strut  Yes  $\bigcirc$ No \newline
Question \hfill $\bigcirc$ \strut  Yes  $\bigcirc$ No \newline
Question \hfill $\bigcirc$ \strut  Yes  $\bigcirc$ No%  <--- % needed
}
  & & & & & \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-8}
\rule[-0.8cm]{0cm}{1cm} & s & & & & & & & \\\cline{1-3}\cline{5-8}
\multicolumn{2}{|P{2.8cm}}{\rule{0cm}{1cm}}  & & & & \multicolumn{3}{P{2.8cm}}{\rule{0cm}{1cm}}  &\\
\hline

\end{tabular}

% document end
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If by "vertical align[ment] of a and b" you mean that you don't want them dangling at the top of the cells, then you need to remove the vertical strut (`\rule`) that you've inserted.

Comment: Or you have to change its vertical position: `\rule[-.4cm]{0pt}{1cm}` looks ok.

Comment: And `\multirow{8}{7.6cm}{%` for a vertically centred `multirow`. You have 6 lines here and want one free above and below. You just gave 3 lines to your `multirow`

Comment: Thx everybody! One little question additionally: How i can set some padding left/right in cell with content question yes/no?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly simpler code, and the use of `\multirowcell` from the `makecell` package. Everything has been vertically centred:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % customize page layout
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow} % multirow for table (rowspan)
\geometry{paper=a4paper, landscape,hmargin=28.5mm,vmargin=20mm}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\cellalign{{p{\dimexpr7.6cm-10pt\relax}}c}
\patchcmd\cellset{\def\arraystretch{1}}{\def\arraystretch{1.12}}{}{}

\setlength\parindent{0cm} % no indent for whole document
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0cm} % padding either side of each column (only horizontal)

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr#1-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}

\newcommand\YesNo{\hfill$\bigcirc$ \strut Yes\hskip0.5em$\bigcirc$ No }

% document start
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{%
    | P{1.4cm}
    | M{1.4cm}
    | M{1.4cm}
    | P{7.6cm}
    | P{6.4cm}
    | P{1.2cm}
    | P{1.2cm}
    | P{1.2cm}
    | P{2.2cm}
    |
    }%

    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\rule[-0.45cm]{0pt}{1cm} a} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{b} \\

    \hline
    0 & \thead{1 & & & & & & & \\ \footnotesize(1)}& 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & \\
    \cline{1-8}
    \rule[-0.45cm]{0pt}{1cm} & & &
    \multirowcell{3}[4pt]{%
    Question \YesNo\\
    Question \YesNo\\%
    Question \YesNo\\%
    Question \YesNo\\%
    Question \YesNo\\%
    Question \YesNo% <--- % needed
    }%
    & & & & & \\
    \cline{1-3}\cline{5-8}
    \rule[-0.45cm]{0pt}{1cm} & s & & & & & & & \\
    \cline{1-3}\cline{5-8}
    \multicolumn{2}{|P{2.8cm}}{\rule[-0.45cm]{0pt}{1cm}} & & & & \multicolumn{3}{P{2.8cm}}{} &\\
    \hline

  \end{tabular}

  % document end
\end{document}
```

[image]